# Pre upgrade backup for Ubuntu/Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup, restore

Well. I'd like to upgrade my parent's box from 8.10 (intrepid) to 10.04 LTS (lucid).

Doing this from the package manager *should* work, but I want to get a backup of the system if things go haywire or something stops working on this laptop. (After all, I *did* have serious gfx-driver problems after my last upgrade.)

The [ubuntu thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=35087) on this is rather vague and googling gets me lost in the details, which I currently do net much care for.

This box has 2 other partitions (apart from swap), one with Windows (came pre-installed, I'll not remove it) and one a FAT32 partition to swap data btw. Ubuntu and Windows (IO prefer to mount the NTFS boot part. r/o)

My specific **question(s)** now are:

- Will backing up 8.10 with tar and restoring this tar file on the upgraded 10.04 work in principle?
- Will I have to do anything about grub when restoring?
- Which toplevel directories do I need to exclude from tar? (`ls /` below)

  bin    dev   initrd.img      lost+found  opt   sbin  tmp  vmlinuz
  boot   etc   initrd.img.old  media       proc  srv   usr  vmlinuz.old
  cdrom  home  lib             mnt         root  sys   var
- What about the symlinks? (initrd.img, vmlinuz)
- When restoring with tar, will it delete any files 10.04 has added to the harddisk?

Note that I'd also be fine using dd to make a full disc image -- but I assume I would then need to boot from the live CD to restore?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The safest solution would be to use dd from live cd. You will need to backup MBR and Ubuntu partition.

To backup MBR (first 512 bytes of the disk where GRUB is installed) run:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/backup_dir/mbr_backup bs=512 count=1
```

To backup your Ubuntu partition (assuming it is /dev/sda3):

```
dd if=/dev/sda3 of=/backup_dir/ubuntu_backup
```

Don't write the backup to FAT32 partition because it would truncate the backup to around 4GB. External drive with ext3 or ntfs partition would be preferred.

To restore grub run:

```
dd if=/backup_dir/mbr_backup of=/dev/sda
```

To restore ubuntu:

```
dd if=/backup_dir/mubuntu_backup of=/dev/sda3
```

Comment: Thanks! Do I *need* to restore grub when restoring the partition via dd? Is it possible to validate the dd image somehow?

Comment: If by restoring grub you mean restoring MBR then it would be only needed if the installation made some changes to MBR and you can't boot into windows or linux after reboot. To validate dd image comparing length of the image and the partition should be sufficient, but to be really sure you would need to compare md5sum of the image with md5sum for the partition (assuming the partition wasn't changed).

Answer (score 3):

If you aren't going to change the partition layout on that PC, what I'd do is use [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) to make a backup of the Ubuntu partitions. Sounds like less work and less worries to me.

Answer (score 1):

[Mondo Rescue](http://www.mondorescue.org/) is a good way to make backups of currently functioning Linux systems before a complicated upgrade.

Per the website:

> Mondo Rescue is a GPL disaster recovery solution. It supports Linux (i386, x86_64, ia64) and FreeBSD (i386). It's packaged for multiple distributions (RedHat, RHEL, SuSE, SLES, Mandriva, Debian, Gentoo).
>
> It supports tapes, disks, network and
> CD/DVD as backup media, multiple
> filesystems, LVM, software and
> hardware Raid.

It should be flexible enough to complete the backup operation for your parents.  Also, if the installation goes south when you aren't around, they should be able to toss the installation DVDs back into the computer to restore a working Linux OS back onto their PC.